# Renaming a form in C# WinForms properly

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms

I'm currently working on a project in **C# WinForms** and I wanted to know how you rename a `Form` properly without breaking the application. I need to change my Form8 to Form9 and I'm assuming that you need to rename the design (name) in the properties window of a form but are there any other steps that I need to take in order to rename correctly?

Comment: Have you tried to see if it works? If the design name change doesn't change it everywhere, right click `Form8`, Refactor > Rename

Comment: if you are working in visual studio: VS has Rename refactoring option https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxxabwd(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Ok thanks , i have not tried it yet as i just wanted to double check first to make sure my application wasn't going to break from doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Pick meaningful names in the first place, something that describes what the form does. Form8 and Form9 tell somebody nothing about what they do.

Comment: Little side note here, instead of renaming it from 'Form8' to 'Form9', why not use a meaningful name like 'LoginForm' or 'Profile'?

Comment: So should i use refactoring or just change the design name, or both? which one is recommended?

Comment: If you are concerned about breaking the code, then make a clean copy/branch to play with.  If it works merge into your source control, if it doesn't, throw it away, no harm done.

Comment: maybe form8 and 9 have meaning in the context of the application? and I think renaming the file will give you the option of renaming the underlying type. I know it works with simple classes like when you start  new library project and you rename the Class1.cs file

Comment: Okay thanks guys, i think i will just make a copy and try it out to prevent anything going wrong. And thanks for the suggestions about naming the forms to something more individual , i was going to initially do that at the start but i just forgot and just carried on with using the generic names. No worries though (:

Answer (score 6):

right click the form in solution explorer, choose 'rename'. Once you've named it then it asks you if you want to change all references(that's refactoring), say yes.

Comment: but in some forms it is not asking about refactoring. How can we do that ?

Comment: @CihanKüsmez it should always prompt you about renaming,saying do you want to change all references.  As a test, try creating a new project and try to right click and rename Form1.cs, see if it prompts you..Then create some new forms, again right click try to rename,do you see it prompt you every time?  it should.Remember this is in solution explorer. renaming them within visual studio itself. Maybe you can find under what conditions/why it isn't in your case. But try it for a simple new example project..If it doesn't then you have a different problem to this one and could make a new question.